# passing array of parameters in ASP .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Creating a Web API through which array of id is passed and returns the result from the OracleDB.

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    public string Getdetails([FromUri] int []id)
    {
       string inconditons = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == id.Length - 1)
            {
                inconditons = inconditons + id[i];
            }
            else
            {
                inconditons = inconditons + id[i] + ", ";
            }
        }
        using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=X;PASSWORD=03JD;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=IN"))
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            var strQuery = @"Select PRIO_CATEGORY_ID as PRIO,LANG_ID as LANG, REC_DATE as REC, REC_USER as RECUSER, DESCR,COL_DESCR AS COL,ROW_DESCR as DROW,ABBR from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where REC_USER  IN (" + inconditons + ");";
            var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
        }
    }
}
```

And called the API as http://localhost:35432/api/Sample?id=1&id=83 it throws an error saying on var queryResult = dbConn.Query(strQuery);
[image]
But if I just give one parameter as below it works

```
var strQuery = @"Select PRIO_CATEGORY_ID as PRIO,LANG_ID as LANG, REC_DATE as REC, REC_USER as RECUSER, DESCR,COL_DESCR AS COL,ROW_DESCR as DROW,ABBR from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where REC_USER  =" +id ;
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is the issue here as a single parameter works. Thanks

Comment: Press on the `View Details` and expand `Internal Exception` property for more accurate information.

Comment: It says {"ORA-00911: invalid character"}

Comment: Do not use concatenated strings to perform your queries. Use [parameterized queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/), otherwise you're vulnerable to errors like this and SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: have you tried by removing ; (semicolon) from the end of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure your don't have any stray characters in your query.

As stated in the comments

> Use parameterized queries, otherwise you're vulnerable to errors like
>   this and SQL Injection attacks.

So pass the `id` array into the parameterized query when executing.

Here is a refactored version of your example.

```
public class SampleController : ApiController {
    public string Getdetails([FromUri] int[] id) {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=h;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T")) {
            dbConn.Open();
            var strQuery = "SELECT PRIO_CATEGORY_ID AS PRIO, LANG_ID AS LANG, REC_DATE AS REC, REC_USER AS RECUSER, DESCR, COL_DESCR AS COL, ROW_DESCR AS DROW, ABBR FROM STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR WHERE REC_USER  IN (:p)";
            var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery, new { p = inconditions });
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NKosi, The issue is it says inconditions is not in current context in  var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery, new { p = inconditions });

Comment: @trx Simple typo. fixed

Comment: Still getting the same error {"ORA-00936: missing expression"} in var queryResult = dbConn.Query<SamModel>(strQuery, new { p = inconditions });

Comment: I tried to add the breakboint and it doesnot return any result query. When use the same query in DB it returns the records

Comment: @trx it Seems to be something with the query statement. checked and I was using the wrong character `@` instead of `:`. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Now I get {"ORA-01722: invalid number"} on the same statement The api I am trying is http://localhost:35432/api/Sample?id=1&id=83

Comment: ok thats because we converted the ids to string when were building the query. I converted it back to an array and passed that in as the parameter.

Comment: I tried giving as as an array as you did now we get {"ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"} I checked all the paranthesis and everything looks good

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me.  It might fail if your `id` array parameter is empty (but it will be a different error than what you see now). Put a breakpoint in your code and inspect the value of that.

Also for converting your array to string, You may use the  `String.Join` method.

```
var ids = String.Join(",",id);
```

This will give the result like `"1,3,5"`, assuming your int array has 3 items ,1,3 and 5

Now you can use this string variable in your query. Also you may consider passing this data as a parameter.

```
 var q= " ...  where REC_USER IN (@ids);" //Please fill the  missing part of query
 var result = con.Query<SomeModel>(q,new { ids });
```